# In TableView How can i show "Showmore" option for displaying more Records?

Tags: iphone

I have used TableView and i am displaying Data coming from the Web.NOW I WANT TO PERFORMING  the Paging TableView so after 5 record i want to show "showmore" Option and by pressing "showmore" It Display remaining data so how it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In your table view, include a cell with the text "Show more...". It should probably also contain a UIActivityIndicator that is hidden at the moment.
- If this cell is tapped, show the activity indicator and load more content from the Web in the background.
- When you have received a response from your web service and have parsed the results, send your table view a `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` message to have it load the new data.
- Depending on whether you want to keep the "Show more" cell or remove it now, either hide the activity indicator and re-enable the cell or delete it by calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.

Comment: suppose there is a case that i have 10 data and at a time i have to display only 5 and after tapping "shomore" the remaining 5 i have to show then what should i do?

Comment: You should do something along the outline that I have laid out in my answer. If you encounter any problems along the way, please ask much more specific questions.

Comment: Actually i have implemented it and i have got all response from the web.For example i have received 10 names that i have taken in the NSDictionary and i want that among 10 first five should be displayed and when i pressed "Showme" option then next five will be displayed.it should look like paging performing from our side.i have taken custom cell for displaying "showme" option.